# Zend Framework 1. Fetch comments

Tags: php, mysql, select, zend-framework, fetch

I can't create an appropriate query which could select all comments connected with one particular image and get those comments authors.
I would like to create a query something like:

```
select a comment where comment_id == image_id && user_id(table comments) == user_id(table users)
```

This is MySQL part:

```
Table 'comments'
id | comment | user_id | image_id |
1  | test 1  |    1    |     1    |
2  | test 2  |    1    |     2    |
3  | test 3  |    2    |     1    |


Table 'users'
id |  name  |
1  |  test1 |
2  |  test2 |


Table 'images'
id |    img     |
1  |  test.jpg  |
2  |  test.jpg  |
3  |  test.jpg  |
4  |  test.jpg  |
```

Controller Part:

```
$imageId = $filter->filter ($request->getParam('id'));
$this->view->imageId = $filter->filter ($request->getParam('id'));
$this->view->imageChosen = $images->fetchRow($images->select()->where('id = ?', $imageId));

$users = new Users();
$userChosen = new Users();
$comments = new Comments();
$this->view->comments = $comments->fetchAll();

$this->view->userChosen = $users->fetchRow($users->select()->where('id = ?', $this->view->imageChosen->author_id));
$this->view->commentsChosen = $comments->fetchAll($comments->select()->where('id = ?', $imageId));
```

View part:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($this->commentsChosen); $i++) {
    echo $this->commentChosen[$i]->comment;
}
```

Right now I only get the very first comment.
What I mean is I need all comments belonging to each picture as well as authors info.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get all comments belonging to each picture.

Controller:

```
$this->view->commentsChosen = $comments->fetchAll($comments->select()->where('image_id = ?', $this->view->imageChosen->id));
```

View:

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($this->commentsChosen); $i++) {
    echo $this->commentsChosen[$i]->comment;
    //Have 'user_id' only
    echo $this->commentsChosen[$i]->user_id;
}
```

However, I still can't get authors details.

Answer (score 2):

As you've said, you can fetch the image info with your query, I'll extend it in order to fetch the user info too:

```
$select = $comments->select()->setIntegrityCheck(false)
                   ->from('comments')
                   ->joinInner('users', 'users.id = comments.user_id')
                   ->where('comments.image_id = ?', $this->view->imageChosen->id);

$this->view->commentsChosen = $comments->fetchAll($select);
```

The generated query would be:

```
SELECT comments.* users.* FROM comments
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = comments.user_id
WHERE comments.image_id = [Your_id_here]
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately I get an error: 'Select query cannot join with another table'. What about iterating through $this->view->commentsChosen? And getting users WHERE id == user_id? This is my idea. However, I haven't got the faintest idea how to write this.

Comment: Check my edit, it should work with the new "setIntegrityCheck(false)" line. Your idea would ideally work, but it's expensive in time and in number of accesses to the DataBase.
This way, we only run one query. Let me know if it works and if not, we'll search another solution.

Comment: Now I get such an error: Unknown column 'image_id' in 'where clause'', while I'm pretty sure such a column exists.

Comment: Check the edit again, please. I'm sure we're pretty close :). I added 'comments.image.id' in the where clause.

Comment: $Saso222 It's similar: Unknown column 'comments.image_id' in 'where clause''

Comment: @Peter Let's try adding a From clause, check the edit.

Comment: It works. How can I access users name in the view part right now?

Comment: echo $this->commentsChosen[$i]->name; shall be working. If not, try to print the whole array to see what's inside (var_dump/echo $this->commentsChosen[$i], or even without the [$i]) and get the correct property.

Comment: Perfect. That's what I was looking for. Thanks for help :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88100/discussion-between-peter-and-saso222).